# 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. using nginx proxy pass to another nginx

Tags: nginx, alias, http-status-code-403, proxypass, httpforbiddenhandler

Im getting this 403 Forbidden error, but in access.log of the server 1 it tells is a 200 OK request, same happens in the server 2 nginx.
Server 1 is with ssl and server 2 using ip, so I'm accesing from server 1 to server's 2 ip:port/signed.

To resume my problem:
[image]

Im getting this forbidden on this location on server 1 (this proxy_pass to server 2 location /signed configure in server 2 nginx):

[image]

And this is my location /signed on server 2:

[image]

When I request server 2 ip:port/signed url it is ok, i can see all files in folder,
but when I request server 1 domain/signed url it returns the 403 Forbidden.

How can I solve this error so I can obtain same answer as the one I get from server 2 /signed location?

Like this: response is in html
[image]